# mysql query to sort alphabetically group by item with count >1 and count = 1 separately on same list

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-order-by

I have a list of listings with

1. Texas with count 5
2. New york with count 6
3. Alabama with count 4
4. LA with 1
5. Boston with 1
6. Washington with 1

I want to order to

1. Alabama
2. Newyork
3. Texas
4. Boston
5. LA
6. Washington

So anything with count(*)>1 should be arrange alphabetically to top of list and anything with count(*)1 should be arrange alphabetically at bottom of list.

Currently i have used

```
 $orderby = 'counter DESC, display_value ASC';
```

but its giving me

1. New york
2. Texas
3. Alabama
4. Boston
5. LA
6. Washington

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can express this as:

```
order by (counter > 1) desc, display_value
```

In a numeric context, a boolean is treated as an integer with true as 1 and false as 0.  So `(count > 1) desc` puts the true values first.  These are then sorted by the `display_value`.

Comment: doesn't work. It shows alabama first but boston on second

Comment: @edd . . . Then something is wrong with your first condition in the `order by`.  All rows with a count greater than 1 should be before the last three.